# what is the equivalant of rxJava onNext and onError in coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, use-case

Hi I have some usecases which are written in Java which uses rxJava. I have converted them to kotlin files and instead of rxJava I have made them into couroutines suspend functions.

In my rxJava code I am making an api call from the usecase and it returns the result but at the same time onNext it does something and onError it does something.

How can I do the same thing in coroutines

here is my rxjava code

```
    @PerApp
public class StartFuellingUseCase {

    @Inject
    App app;
    @Inject
    CurrentOrderStorage orderStorage;
    @Inject
    FuelOrderRepository repository;

    @Inject
    StartFuellingUseCase() {
        // empty constructor for injection usage
    }

    public Observable<GenericResponse> execute(Equipment equipment) {
        if (orderStorage.getFuelOrder() == null) return null;

        DateTime startTime = new DateTime();
        TimestampedAction action = new TimestampedAction(
                app.getSession().getUser().getId(), null, startTime
        );

        return repository.startFuelling(orderStorage.getFuelOrder().getId(), action)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(response -> onSuccess(startTime, equipment))
                .doOnError(this::onError);
    }

    private void onSuccess(DateTime startTime, Equipment equipment) {
        if (orderStorage.getFuelOrder() == null) return;

        orderStorage.getFuelOrder().setStatus(FuelOrderData.STATUS_FUELLING);
        equipment.getTimes().setStart(startTime);

        app.saveState();
    }

    private void onError(Throwable e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error calling started fuelling! %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have re written the code in Kotlin using coroutines usecases

```
 @PerApp
class StartFuellingUseCaseCoroutine  @Inject constructor(
    private val currentOrderStorage: CurrentOrderStorage,
    private val fuelOrderRepository: FuelOrderRepository,
    private val app: App
): UseCaseCoroutine<GenericResponse, StartFuellingUseCaseCoroutine.Params>() {

    override suspend fun run(params: Params): GenericResponse {
        val startTime = DateTime()
        val action = TimestampedAction(
            app.session.user.id, null, startTime
        )
        return fuelOrderRepository.startFuelling(
            currentOrderStorage.fuelOrder!!.id,
            action
        )
        //SHOULD RETURN THE VALUE FROM THE fuelOrderRepository.startFuelling
        //AND ALSO
        //ON NEXT
        //CALL onSuccess PASSING startTime and equipment
        //ON ERROR
        //CALL onError
    }

    private fun onSuccess(startTime: DateTime, equipment: Equipment) {
        if (currentOrderStorage.getFuelOrder() == null) return
        currentOrderStorage.getFuelOrder()!!.setStatus(FuelOrderData.STATUS_FUELLING)
        equipment.times.start = startTime
        app.saveState()
    }

    private fun onError(errorMessage: String) {
        Timber.e(errorMessage, "Error calling started fuelling! %s", errorMessage)
    }

    data class Params(val equipment: Equipment)
}
```

Can you please suggest how can i call onSuccess and onError similar to how we have in rxjava onnext and onError.

could you please suggest how to fix this

thanks
R

Comment: If you are looking for RxJava like operators, you need to look into kotlin flows. Coroutines are made for multi-concurrency. Flows are made for handling asynchronous work by using various operators that they come up with.

Answer (score 3):

You can using Kotlin Flow like converted example below:

**RxJava**

```
private fun observable(
    value: Int = 1
): Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.create { emitter ->
        emitter.onNext(value)
        emitter.onError(RuntimeException())
    }
}
```

**Flow:**

```
private fun myFlow(
    value: Int = 1
): Flow<Int> {
    return flow {
        emit(value)
        throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

For more detail : https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow

Answer (score 1):

convert startFuelling to flow using `flowOf`, you can do below

```
return flowOf(repository
       .startFuelling(orderStorage.getFuelOrder().getId(), action))
       .onEach{response -> onSuccess(startTime, equipment)}
       .catch{e -> onError(e) }
       .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) //this will make above statements to execute on IO
```

if you want to collect it on main thread, you can use `launchIn`

```
.onEach{ } 
.launchIn(mainScope)//could be lifeCycleScope/viewModelScope

//or

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{
   flow.collect{}
}
```

Comment: `launchIn` takes CoroutineScope (not CoroutineContext)

Comment: Yea, makes sense updated code accordingly, thanks @AnimeshSahu

Comment: Hi Rajan, Start fuelling returns a GenericResponse but not a flow

Comment: @BRDroid updated the code to make it as flow

Comment: thank you for the edit, I am going to try that update you back. really helpfulll